# React router v6 - no redirection

Tags: reactjs, router, react-navigation-v6

Can anyone tell me why redirect is not working for me? It is supposed to redirect from the "admin" page to the "login" page. I'm putting the code here because it's a few lines torn from the entire application. For clarity - react router 6.

```
const AdminPage = () => {
  const permission = false;
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route
        path="/admin"
        element={(permission
          ? (<h3>Panel admina - dzień dobry</h3>)
          : (<Navigate replace to="/login"/>))}
      />
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

Comment: Any error in the console?

Comment: Hey this isn’t solving your code but my usual way of redirecting is to check permission inside routes so if(permission) then route else redirect

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the Routes with BrowserRouter.

```
import { BrowserRouter, Navigate, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
```

```js
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/admin"
          element={
            permission ? (
              <h3>Panel admina - dzień dobry</h3>
            ) : (
              <Navigate replace to="/login" />
            )
          }
        />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Thanks to everyone for trying to help. I found a bug. Here is his solution.

```
const AdminPage = () => {
    const permission = false;
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path="" element={(permission ? (<h3>Panel admina - dzień dobry</h3>) : (<Navigate replace to="/login"/>)
            )}/>
        </Routes>
    );
}

export default AdminPage;
```